# How to configure ZAP for Desktop Appliation

Tags: penetration-test, proxy, zap

I have used ZAP for performing MiTM for Web Applications, what are the settings or methods to perfrom MitM for a Desktop Application ?

Is there a way you could setup ZAP as a system proxy so you can monitor the entire traffic going from the localhost ?

Comment: Have you tried using it as a system-wide proxy?

Comment: I'm not aware of how I could use it as a system wide proxy. Could you how I could configure that ? Any resource or links?

Comment: Is there a way that the desktop application can specify which proxy to talk through?  Else, you may have to put a transparent egress proxy.

Comment: Can I not just monitor the entire traffic system level there by also seeing the desktop traffic using this manner ?

Comment: Am adding the content for above answer
sometimes proxy tools wont work with desktop application so on that time use echomirage()
if the application is based on java then use JavaSnoop

Answer (score 1):

If the application honours the system-wide proxy settings, you can configure them on Windows via the Internet Options window, or on Linux using the `http_proxy` environment variable. If the application will not communicate through a proxy, you're stuck because Zap does not support transparent proxying of traffic.

If you need transparent proxying of web traffic, I recommend [Burp Suite](https://portswigger.net/burp) for this job because it's so simple to set up. Burp calls this feature [invisible proxying](https://portswigger.net/burp/help/proxy_options_invisible) and you can configure it in your project's options. The idea is that you set up a local listening "proxy" on the same port as the target server, and have that proxy connect out to the real server's IP address on the same port, transparently forwarding all traffic back and forth rather than using a proxy protocol like SOCKS.

There are two easy ways to coerce the application into talking to your transparent proxy rather than the real server. The first is by modifying the application's config files (or binaries) to point to 127.0.0.1 rather than the real server, although this can cause problems because the application will send a `Host` request header containing that IP rather than the real domain. The other way, which is more reliable, is to add the domain to your hosts file so that it resolves to 127.0.0.1.

If the connection is HTTPS, you'll need to export Burp's CA from the config tab and install it on your OS so that you can properly man-in-the-middle it.

If the protocol turns out to be binary rather than HTTP(S) then you could use [CANAPE](https://github.com/ctxis/canape) in the same way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have used Burp but had no idea about this feature. I'm playing around and will update the thread once I have it resolved and working!